# Get interval value from SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem that I haven't figured out a good solution to. Basically, imagine you have a table "discounts" that lists some weeks and discounts.

```html
--Week--Discount--
2 -- 60%
4 -- 50% 
8 -- 40%
```

What above says is that between weeks 2 and 4 the discount is 60%.
Between 4 and 8 it is 50%, and so on.

In another table I would have a list of weeks and Would like to join my discounts table, refering to the discount limit. So for week 9 it would be 40%. For week 3 it would be 60%.

I can join the discount table on itself to give me the "min/max" values per bracket, but from there I'm not sure how the join would look to determine the discount.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `outer apply`:

```
select w.*, d.discount
from weeks w outer apply
     (select top (1) d.*
      from discounts d
      where d.week <= w.week
      order by d.week desc
     ) d;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `subquery` :

```
select *, (select top (1) d1.Discount 
           from discounts d1 
           where d1.week <= w.week
           order by d1.week desc
          ) as discount
from week w;
```